# Error while trying to insert data into database using hibernate. error is Constraint Violation exception (using Oracle DB)

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

The error is at the line session.save(customer).CUSTOMER and EventRequest are the tables name. custno. is the primary key in CUSTOMER table and EventRequest tables.

Is there any issue in the mapping in the customer and EventRequest files.

The custno. shouldn't be null in the CUSTOMER table, but hibernate is not inserting custno. in the CUSTOMER TABLE. This is what the hibernate does: it's missing the custno. column.

insert into CUSTOMER (Internal, address, city, contact, custname, phone, state, zip) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

The error trace:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

**Hibernate: insert into CUSTOMER (Internal, address, city, contact, custname, phone, state, zip) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)**

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractSelectingDelegate.performInsert(AbstractSelectingDelegate.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2975)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3487)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:764)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:756)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:752)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.icdab.www.icdab_first.App.persistAnnotatedLists(App.java:67)
    at com.icdab.www.icdab_first.App.main(App.java:89)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SYSTEM"."CUSTOMER"."CUSTNO")

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:215)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:58)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:943)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1075)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3820)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3897)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1361)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
```

"The error says cannot insert NULL into ("SYSTEM"."CUSTOMER"."CUSTNO")".
App.Java:

```
package com.icdab.www.icdab_first;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session; 
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration; 
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder; 
/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    private static SessionFactory factory;
    private static ServiceRegistry registry;
    // private void init(){
       // System.out.println("in init");
    static {
        Configuration config = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
                /*.addAnnotatedClass(CompundKey.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Customer.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Employee.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(EventPlan.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(EventPlanLine.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(EventRequest.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Facility.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Location.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(ResourceTbl.class) */

        // learn why did you use the annotatedclass and configuration.

          registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
          factory=config.buildSessionFactory(registry);
    }
//  }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void persistAnnotatedLists(){
        Configuration config = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

          registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
          factory=config.buildSessionFactory(registry);
       //  Session session_one = factory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession(); 
        session.beginTransaction();
        Customer customer = new Customer(); 
        customer.setAddress("address123");
        customer.setCity("lansing");
        customer.setContact("1632 ne ave");
        customer.setCustname("john");
        customer.setCustno("1234");
        customer.setInternal("internal");
        customer.setPhone(122345679);
        customer.setState("OR");
        customer.setZip(97654);
        System.out.println("the setter methods completed");
        List<EventRequest> ers = new ArrayList<EventRequest>();

        ers.add(new EventRequest(123,new Date(92,5,1),new Date(91,5,1),new Date(93,5,1),"av",123,456,124));

        ers.add(new EventRequest(1234,new Date(92,5,2),new Date(91,5,2),new Date(93,5,2),"av",124,457,125));
        customer.setEventrequests(ers);

        //here is the error 
        session.save(customer); 


        System.out.println("befor commit");
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("after commit");
        System.out.println("done persist");
    }
    private void retrieveList(){
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction(); 

        List list = session.createQuery("from com.icdab.www.icdab_first.Customer").list();

        for (Object object : list) {
            System.out.println("** List items: "+object);
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("Done retrieve");
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        App app = new App();
        //app.init();
        app.persistAnnotatedLists();
        app.retrieveList();
    }
}
```

Customer.java:

```
package com.icdab.www.icdab_first;
import javax.persistence.*;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;

import java.util.List;
import com.icdab.www.icdab_first.EventRequest;

@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {
@Id 
@Column(name="custno",nullable=false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private String custno;

private String custname; 
private String address;
private String Internal; 
private String contact; 
private int phone;
private String city; 
private String state; 
private int zip; 


//added block to define the onetomany relationship b.w tables.

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="custno")
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
private List<EventRequest> eventrequests;


public List<EventRequest> getEventrequests() {
    return eventrequests;
}
public void setEventrequests(List<EventRequest> eventrequests) {
    this.eventrequests = eventrequests;
}




public String getCustno() {
    return custno;
}
public void setCustno(String custno) {
    this.custno = custno;
}
public String getCustname() {
    return custname;
}
public void setCustname(String custname) {
    this.custname = custname;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public String getInternal() {
    return Internal;
}
public void setInternal(String internal) {
    Internal = internal;
}
public String getContact() {
    return contact;
}
public void setContact(String contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}
public int getPhone() {
    return phone;
}
public void setPhone(int phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getState() {
    return state;
}
public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}
public int getZip() {
    return zip;
}
public void setZip(int zip) {
    this.zip = zip;
}
}
```

EventRequest.java:

```
package com.icdab.www.icdab_first;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Time; 
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;
import com.icdab.www.icdab_first.Customer;

@Entity
@Table(name="EVENTREQUEST")
public class EventRequest {
@Id 
@Column(name="EVENTNO",nullable=false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int eventno; 
private Date dateheld;
private Date datereq; 
//private int facno; 
private Date dateauth;
private String status; 
private int estcost;
private int estaudience;
private int budno;

public EventRequest(){
}

public EventRequest(int eventno, Date dateheld,
        Date datereq, Date dateauth,String status,
        int estcost, int estaudience,int budno)
{
    setEventno(eventno);
    setDateheld(dateheld);
    setDatereq(datereq);
    setDateauth(dateauth);
    setStatus(status);
    setEstcost(estcost);
    setEstaudience(estaudience);
    setBudno(budno);
}
// one to many mapping eventrequest and eventplan 
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="eventno")
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
private List<EventPlan> eventplans;
public List<EventPlan> getEventplans() {
    return eventplans;
}
public void setEventplans(List<EventPlan> eventplans) {
    this.eventplans = eventplans;
}


public int getEventno() {
    return eventno;
}
public void setEventno(int eventno) {
    this.eventno = eventno;
}
public Date getDateheld() {
    return dateheld;
}
public void setDateheld(Date dateheld) {
    this.dateheld = dateheld;
}
public Date getDatereq() {
    return datereq;
}
public void setDatereq(Date datereq) {
    this.datereq = datereq;
}

/*
public int getCustno() {
    return custno;
}
public void setCustno(int custno) {
    this.custno = custno;
}
*/

/*
public int getFacno() {
    return facno;
}
public void setFacno(int facno) {
    this.facno = facno;
}

*/
public Date getDateauth() {
    return dateauth;
}
public void setDateauth(Date dateauth) {
    this.dateauth = dateauth;
}
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
public int getEstcost() {
    return estcost;
}
public void setEstcost(int estcost) {
    this.estcost = estcost;
}
public int getEstaudience() {
    return estaudience;
}
public void setEstaudience(int estaudience) {
    this.estaudience = estaudience;
}
public int getBudno() {
    return budno;
}
public void setBudno(int budno) {
    this.budno = budno;
}

}
```

Comment: Once drop your `Customer` table and run the application

Comment: Why are you setting `custno` when it is defined as an `@Id` in the Entity? `GenerationType.IDENTITY` means that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using a database identity column.

Comment: I removed the setters (for custno.) on the customer class and (eventno. and custno.) on the EventRequest class. still have the same issue. "says can't insert null into custno". @LuayAbdulraheem .

Comment: What DB are you using? Can you change to @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) and check what happens

Comment: I'm using Oracle DB, using GenerationType.AUTO gives me   "org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet". caused by  "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist". @LuayAbdulraheem

Comment: Using `Auto` means that the persistence provider should pick an appropriate strategy for the particular database. Create a DB sequence then try again.

Comment: @Luay Adbulraheem Thanks Luay, using the Sequence worked, I'm having an another issue Can you if possible answer that one. the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44743986/error-while-trying-to-insert-data-in-to-child-table-using-hibernate-integrity-co?noredirect=1#comment76490123_44743986

Comment: Good to hear that, let me add an answer in order to help others facing the same issue.

Comment: And please update the title to state that you are using Oracle database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GenerationType.IDENTITY` means that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using a database identity column. There is no such thing called "identity" columns in Oracle as of Oracle 11g (Available in 12c). So in your case, you will have to create a Database sequence and then use `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` or `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq")` to generate values for primary key fields.