# Error while trying to insert data in to child table using hibernate.Integrity constraint violation

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Parent table: (Customer_one) used the hibernate Cascade and CascadeType. Constraint violation error while trying to commit the transaction in app.persistAnnoatedLists() method. (I was able to insert the data into the parent table but couldn't insert data into child table), The Error message is (it seems the foreign key in child table is not mapped with parent key, using Oracle DB and primary key generation type  used is sequence):

Tables: 
CUSTOMER_ONE:
PK ---> custnone. 
EVENTREQUEST_ONE: 
PK ----> eventnoone. 
FK ----> custnoone.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3067)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3509)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:339)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1234)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at icdabs.econd.icdab.App.persistAnnotatedLists(App.java:75)
    at icdabs.econd.icdab.App.main(App.java:96)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.EVENTREQUEST_FK_ONE) violated - parent key not found

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:215)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:58)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:943)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1075)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3820)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3897)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1361)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
```

customer_one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER_ONE")
public class Customer_one {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "custnoone", nullable = false)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="mysequence", sequenceName="my_seq",allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="mysequence")
    private int custnoone;

private String custnameone;
private String addressone;
private String Internalone;
private String contactone;
private int phoneone;
private String cityone;
private String stateone;
private int zipone;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="custnoone")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    private List<EventRequest_one> EventRequest_ones = new ArrayList<EventRequest_one>(); 



    public List<EventRequest_one> getEventRequest_ones() {
        return EventRequest_ones;
    }
    public void setEventRequest_ones(List<EventRequest_one> eventRequest_ones) {
        EventRequest_ones = eventRequest_ones;
    }
```

EventRequest_one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EVENTREQUEST_ONE")
public class EventRequest_one {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "eventnoone", nullable = false)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="mysequence", sequenceName="my_seq",allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="mysequence")
    private int eventnoone;
        private Date dateheldone;
    private Date datereqone;
    private int facnoone;
    private Date dateauthone;
    private String statusone;
    private int estcostone;
    private int estaudienceone;
    private int budnoone;
//  @Transient
    @Column(name="CUSTNOONE")
    private int custnoone;


    public EventRequest_one() {
    }

    public EventRequest_one( Date dateheld, Date datereq, Date dateauth, String status, int estcost,
            int estaudience, int budno, int facno) {
    //  setCustnoone(custno);
    //  setEventnoone(eventno);
        setDateheldone(dateheld);
        setDatereqone(datereq);
        setDateauthone(dateauth);
        setStatusone(status);
        setEstcostone(estcost);
        setEstaudienceone(estaudience);
        setBudnoone(budno);
        setFacnoone(facno);
    }


public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }
}
```

Main (App.java):

```
public class App 
{
    private static SessionFactory factory;
    private static ServiceRegistry registry;

    static {
        Configuration config = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml"); 
          registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
          factory=config.buildSessionFactory(registry);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void persistAnnotatedLists(){
        Configuration config = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

          registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
          factory=config.buildSessionFactory(registry);

        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession(); 
        session.beginTransaction();
        Customer_one customer = new Customer_one(); 
        customer.setAddressone("address123");
        customer.setCityone("lansing");
        customer.setContactone("1632 ne ave");
        customer.setCustnameone("john");
    //    customer.setCustnoone(12);
        customer.setInternalone("I");
        customer.setPhoneone(122345679);
        customer.setStateone("OR");
        customer.setZipone(97654);

        List<EventRequest_one> er = new ArrayList<EventRequest_one>();
         er.add(new EventRequest_one(new Date(92,5,1),new Date(91,5,1),new Date(93,5,1),"av",123,456,124,12));

    session.save(customer);
         customer.setEventRequest_ones(er);

    for(EventRequest_one EventRequest_Ones : er){
            System.out.println("inside for loop");
        session.save(EventRequest_Ones);

        }


        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
public static void main (String[] args){
        App app = new App();

        app.persistAnnotatedLists();
    //  app.retrieveList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you mentioned the answer yourself: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_02291_integrity_constraint_string_string_violated_parent_key_not_found.htm

Comment: I couldn't figure out where the mistake is. I checked the Oracle DB and the  primary and Foreign key match each other and are referenced correctly. So the issue might be with the hibernate mapping. Can you tell me what am i doing wrong with the mapping. @RahulRaj

Comment: Removed the field custnoone in EventRequest_one class and getters and settters. and changed the database FK field constraint NOT NULL to NULL. Then it worked.

Comment: why NOT NULL constraint has to removed on foreign key in EventRequest_one table in DB. Otherwise i get the error as foriegnkey cannot be null.

Comment: First you will need to fix the relationship mapping of the two entities. In your Customer_one entity, the mapping should be `@OneToMany(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="customer_one") private List<EventRequest_one> EventRequest_ones`, and on the EventRequest_one side the mapping should look like: `@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="custnoone")
    public Customer_one customer_one;`
You can find help here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html